# How to get number of random points around one point in iphone maps?

Tags: iphone, ios, dictionary, geolocation, mkmapview

I am developing one iphone application which contains maps. Starting screen is navigation screen where user can select location, lets say florida. Now when User selects florida i want to pick up at least six random points (latitude and longitude of points so that I can put annotation) from florida only.

I do not have DB so that I can not fetch 5 points from DB for florida and place them.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be quite hard if you don't have anything to tell you the shape and size of the area you are trying to produce random points within. Harikrishnan had given you a good start, though increasing the lat and long by 0.0001 each time is hardly random. At Florida's coordintes (28.0908° N, 81.9604° W according to Google) moving 0.0001 in both directions is only [14m away](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), so you're unlikely to leave Florida at that speed.

You could adjust Harikirshnan's method by using a random number instead of 0.0001, but you still need to know how big the area is that your user is looking at. Having 5 points all 14m when you're looking at a state, or even a city, is not much good.

Maybe you need to look more closely at what you are trying to achieve. If the points don't represent geographical data then why are you putting them on a map. If they do and they represent the entire area and not a single point then the best I can think of is to generate random points based on the maprect that Apple returns for the location the user has chosen. (roughly speaking that would be `mapX = random*maprect.size.width + maprect.origin.x`). And then incase you have an area like Florida that is not perfectly shaped like your MKMapView you'd need to reverse geocode to see if the point you picked really is within Florida (i.e. send the coords to Apple and check the address).

Or, you could consider now showing the data on the map

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSInteger i;
    double offset=0.0001;
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++){
        double newlatitude=location.coordinate.longitude+offset;
        double newlongitude=location.coordinate.longitude+offset;
        NSLog(@"%f ,%f",newlatitude,newlongitude );
        offset+=0.0001;
    }
```

Comment: According to me resultant location might possible will go away from florida. This will definitely fail for small regions like Mumbai.

Comment: Edited the answer. Please check